# SQLite database no such table _20180121

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am giving tale name as **_TodayDate** but whenever data changes it says there is no such table exist.

**Here is my DatabaseHandler**

It was working yesterday but whenever the date changes the app crashes.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version    
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "entryManager";

    private static  String getTableName(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String date = "_"+df.format(calendar.getTime());
        return date; 
    }

    // Contacts table name
    private String TABLE_DATE = getTableName();
    //String formattedDate = DateFormat.getDateFormat().format(new Date());

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ROLL = "Roll";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "Date";
    private static final String KEY_TIME = "Time";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_ENTRY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_DATE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ROLL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," +  KEY_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ENTRY_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DATE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addEntry(EntryDetails entryDetails) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ROLL, entryDetails.getRoll()); // ROll
        values.put(KEY_DATE, entryDetails.getDate()); // Date
        values.put(KEY_TIME, entryDetails.getTime()); //Time

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_DATE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    EntryDetails getEntryDetails(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DATE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_ROLL, KEY_DATE, KEY_TIME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        EntryDetails entryDetails = new EntryDetails(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        // return contact
        return entryDetails;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<EntryDetails> getAllEntries() {
        List<EntryDetails> entryDetailses = new ArrayList<EntryDetails>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DATE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                EntryDetails entryDetails = new EntryDetails();
                entryDetails.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                entryDetails.setRoll(cursor.getString(1));
                entryDetails.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
                entryDetails.setTime(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                entryDetailses.add(entryDetails);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return entryDetailses;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateEntry(EntryDetails entryDetails) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ROLL, entryDetails.getRoll());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, entryDetails.getDate());
        values.put(KEY_TIME, entryDetails.getTime());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_DATE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(entryDetails.get_id()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteEntry(EntryDetails entryDetails) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_DATE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(entryDetails.get_id()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getEntryCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DATE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat. It is saying that no such table exists.

```
    E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: _20180121
    01-21 00:31:32.078 7788-
    7788/com.jagdishchoudhary.iitgandhinagarmesssystem E/AndroidRuntime: 
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.jagdishchoudhary.iitgandhinagarmesssystem, PID: 7788

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jagdishchoudhary.iitgandhinagarmesssystem/com.jagdishchoudhary.iitgandhinagarmesssystem.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: _20180121 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM _20180121
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: _20180121 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM _20180121
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
    at com.jagdishchoudhary.iitgandhinagarmesssystem.DatabaseHandler.getAllEntries(DatabaseHandler.java:117)
    at com.jagdishchoudhary.iitgandhinagarmesssystem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have experienced, whenever the date changes the table name will change. That is because you are getting the current date as the table name. However, no such table will be created, except when the App is first run as the `onCreate` method will only run when the database, the container for the table(s), is created i.e. it will only run once.

**The correct solution would be to not use a dynamic table name instead used a fixed table name. If the date is an important factor you should have a column for the date in the table (as you have) and then use this column to distinguish data.**

---

If you really wanted a table per date then you could amend to table definition to include `IF NOT EXISTS` in the `onCreate` method and then call this when constructing the DatabaseHandeler.

So you could do something like:-

1) Amend the DatabaseHandler's `onCreate` method so that the table definition includes `IF NOT EXISTS` :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_ENTRY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TABLE_DATE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ROLL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," +  KEY_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ENTRY_TABLE);
}
```

2) Amend the DatabaseHandler's Constructor to always call `onCreate`. :-

```
public DatabaseHandlerDates(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    onCreate(this.getWritableDatabase()); //<<<< ADDED
}
```

**Warnings! regarding using multiple/dynamic tables**

- the `onUpgrade` method would be insufficient as it would only DROP and recreate the current date's table. All other tables would not be upgraded. (you could ascertain all the tables by extract the list of tables from the sqlite_master table.)
- If the date changed whilst using the App you could end up using 2 tables within the App i.e. you may get unexpected results.
- An ever increasing number of tables would exist, unless managed.

---

### Another alternative

You could use the `ALTER TABLE` sql statement to `RENAME` the table name. However, you would then have to ascertain the previous table name in order to RENAME it (again trawl through the sqlite_master table).

Processing the table/data would then be no different to the proposed correct solution. Except that a date changed whilst using the App could result in a crash due to table not found (i.e. any new instances of DatabaseHandler, would use the new date and ALTER the table name unless catered for (perhaps force a restart of the App)).

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now I m able to create tables date wise.